# How to extract content between pair of <<" ">> in Unix

Tags: unix, sed

```
<<"  
72306735   
">>  

<<"  
72306735 35623130 
30000000   
">>  

<<"  
select * from emp  
where id=1   
">>
```

expected output:

```
72306735  
72306735 35623130   
30000000   
select * from emp    
where id=1
```

i tried with sed like:

```
sed -n '/<<"/,/">>/p' script.txt
```

output :

```
<<"  
72306735  
">>  
<<"  
72306735 35623130  
30000000  
">>  
<<"  
select * from emp  
where id=1  
">>
```

please help me with this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Use

```
sed -n '/<<"/,/">>/ { //! p; }' script.txt
```

The `//` attempts the most recently attempted regex again. When used as shown, the most recently attempted regex is the one that determined if the current line is part of the pattern range `/<<"/,/">>/`. In the first line of the range, that is the pattern that matched the first line, from then on it is the pattern that will match the last.

The practical upshot is that it matches the beginning and finishing lines of the range, and so `//!p` means to print only if the current line is not one of them.

The use of `//` is not limited to a `{}` block. You could also write

```
sed '/<<"/,/">>/!d; //d' script.txt
```

Wherein `/<<"/,/">>/!d` deletes all lines that are not part of the range, and `//d` deletes the border lines because `//`, at that point, matches the first and last line of the range.